# Updating Image Using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

I have a NodeJS app that is displaying an image. The image (saved in a local directory) gets updated after a certain time by an OpenCV script. However, when the image is updated, the update does not show on my app until I refresh the page. Does anyone know how I can have my image update automatically?

Here is how I serve the image from a directory as a static file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();    
var publicDir = require('path').join(__dirname,'/public');
app.use(express.static(publicDir));
```

With the code above, I can access my image using this directory:
http://localhost/images/myImage.jpg

Does anyone have an idea of how I can have my image be updated automatically? Or recommend something different for my use case? I don't know if my approach to the problem is the right one.

Comment: [This post might be useful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet).  Basically, to automatically get the updated version you will probably have to occasionally ping your backend to see if there's an updated version or use a websocket to notify the front end that a new version is available.  You might also need to use some sort of cachebusting measure to make sure you pull a fresh version.  This is off the top of my head-- someone may yet answer with a better solution.

Comment: Indeed you are looking at this problem the wrong way. There's nothing simple you can do on the server side to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload) to refresh the page automatically from the server side. This might be helpful for you. 
How to reload manually is explained in the documentation.

```
reloadServer = reload(app);
watch.watchTree(__dirname + "/public", function (f, curr, prev) {
// Fire server-side reload event
reloadServer.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Socket.IO   http://socket.io/#how-to-use

when the server decides to broadcast a change use:

`io.sockets.emit('update-msg', { data: 'this is the data'});`

on the client first connect socket.io and then wait for the "update-msg" event and update your dom:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('update-msg', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    $('#mydiv').html(msg.data)
});
```